# Unable to find main class when running mvn sping-boot:build-image

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven

I've a maven multimodule project

```
Project
|--- executable
|       |--- src
|       |--- pom.xml
|--- core
|       |--- src
|       |--- pom.xml
|--- pom.xml
```

The root pom.xml looks like this

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>

<groupId>com.playgrounds</groupId>
<artifactId>playgrounds-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<modules>
    <module>executable</module>
    <module>core</module>
</modules>
```

The exacutable module has a main class and the pom.xml looks like this

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.playgrounds</groupId>
    <artifactId>playgrounds-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>executable</artifactId>
<name>executable</name>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.playgrounds</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The core module doesn't have a main class, and it looks like this.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.playgrounds</groupId>
    <artifactId>playgrounds-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>core</artifactId>
<name>core</name>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

The command mvn clean package generates a SUCCESS output, however when I run the mvn spring-boot:build-image command, I get an error on the core module: The main class has not been found... Any ideas? I searched in the spring-boot documentation and I couldn't find what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

When you invoke a Maven goal like `spring-boot:build-image` from the root of a multi-module project, Maven will attempt to run to the goal on every module. In this case, you only want to build an image from the `executable` module, not from the `core` module. The best way to handle a situation like this is to modify the configuration of the executable module to attach the `spring-boot:build-image` goal to another goal like `package` so that it gets invoked only for that module.

You can do this using by modifying the `executable` module `pom.xml` as shown in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image):

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>build-image</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

And then running `mvn package`.

Comment: The docs recommend using ‘build-image-no-fork’.  Use build-image-no-fork when binding the goal to the package lifecycle. This goal is similar to build-image but does not fork the lifecycle to make sure package has run

Comment: Thanks for the comment. `build-image-no-fork` was added after this answer was written. You can certainly use that goal if it fits your needs.