# build-image-no-fork getting executed during `mvn clean install verify`

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

[Following on from this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image) linked to from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69599850/unable-to-find-main-class-when-running-mvn-sping-bootbuild-image), I have set up my Spring Boot multi module project to use the `build-image-no-fork` goal in the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` executions.

POM excerpt:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <image>
                        <name>registry.gitlab.com/${project.name}:${project.version}</name>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-image-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I was only expecting it to run when I used the `mvn package` command, but it is running when I do `mvn clean install verify`

I have tried to add the `phase` section of the `execution` but that did nothing either.

[Link to the GitHub repo](https://github.com/SSmale/SpringBoot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So better understanding [maven lifecycle of goals and phases](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-goals-phases) and how the commands work along with [maven profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-profiles) I have a working solution.

When you run `mvn install` it will run all the other phases before it.

> - validate: check if all information necessary for the build is    available
> - compile: compile the source code
> - test-compile: compile the    test source code
> - test: run unit tests
> - package: package compiled    source code into the distributable format (jar, war, …)
> - integration-test: process and deploy the package if needed to run    integration tests
> - install: install the package to a local repository
> - deploy: copy the package to the remote repository

so it will run validate, compile, test, test, package, integration and install.

Now we know why, how do we stop it? Profiles.

Add a property named sensibly for what we want to do, I called mine `skip.docker` and set it to the default you need, true in this case.

then create a profile definition that sets it to the opposite

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dockerise</id>
            <properties>
                <skip.docker>false</skip.docker>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

finally, hook into the skip config property of the goal

```
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-image-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${skip.docker}</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
```

now it will auto skip, but run when we add the `-P dockerise` flag